# change datetime format of datatable.js from ex. (Oct 24 2017 06:08:53:000AM) to (2017-10-24 06:08:53.000)

Tags: javascript, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap, datatables-1.10

`Oct 24 2017 06:08:53:000AM` - (Default output of datatable.js)

`2017-10-24 06:08:53.000` - Here's what I extracted from SQL server

I want the output to be the same as what I got from SQL server

[Sample Screenshot of DataTable.js output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQimb.png)

[Sample Screenshot of SQL server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXjOG.png)

I'm using this code to call the table

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myTable').dataTable({
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

But the format automatically change and I'm trying to search for some information how to change the datetime format to become the same as what I got in SQL server.

HTML CODE for datatable.js

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
                <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>Mobile Number</th>  
                        <th>First Name</th>  
                        <th>Last Name</th>  
                        <th>DateTime</th>  
                        <th>Message</th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  

                <tbody>  
                    <?php 
                    $z = 0; 
                    $x = 0;
                    $query_qmobile = "select distinct "
                    . "phone_book.s_mobile_number as 'Mobile Number', "
                    . "phone_book.s_first_name as 'First Name', "
                    . "phone_book.s_last_name as 'Last Name', "
                    . "inbox.dt_datetime as 'Date', "
                    . "inbox.s_message as 'Message' "
                    . "from phone_book, inbox "
                    . "where phone_book.s_mobile_number = inbox.s_sender "
                    . "order by dt_datetime DESC";

                    $result_qmobile = mssql_query($query_qmobile);
                    $numRows_qmobile = mssql_num_rows($result_qmobile); //TOTAL ROW COUNTS

                    $data_q4 = array();
                    while($row=mssql_fetch_assoc($result_qmobile)){
                    $data_q4[]= $row;
                    }

                    for($x;$x<$numRows_qmobile;$x++){
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td> '.$data_q4[$z]['Mobile Number'].' </td>';
                    echo '<td> '.$data_q4[$z]['First Name'].' </td>';
                    echo '<td> '.$data_q4[$z]['Last Name'].' </td>';
                    echo '<td> '.$data_q4[$z]['Date'].' </td>'; //THIS IS THE PART THAT CONVERT THE DATA
                    echo '<td> '.$data_q4[$z]['Message'].' </td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    $z++;
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>  
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```js
document.write(ConvertDate("Oct 24 2017 06:08:53:000AM"));

function ConvertDate(string){
 var date = {
         month : "",
          day : "",
          year : "",
          hours : "",
          minutes : "",
          seconds : "",
          milliseconds : "",
          period : ""
      };
      
   var dateArr = string.split(" ");
      var timeArr = dateArr[3].split(":");
      
      date.month = function () {
            // a dirty trick to get the numeric value
            var value = new Date(dateArr[0] + " 1").getMonth()
         return value < 10 ? "0" + value : value;
      }();
      date.day = dateArr[1];
      date.year = dateArr[2];
      date.hours = timeArr[0];
      date.minutes = timeArr[1];
      date.seconds = timeArr[2];
      date.milliseconds = timeArr[3].substring(0, 3);
      date.period = timeArr[3].replace(date.milliseconds, "");
      
      return date.year+"-"+date.month+"-"+date.day+" "+(date.period == "PM" ? date.hours + 12 : date.hours)+":"+date.minutes+":"+date.seconds+"."+date.milliseconds;
}
```

Then form jquery

```
$("#myTable <some selector for your date time column>").each(function(){
     $(this).html(ConvertDate($(this).html()));

});
```

**UPDATED**

```
-CHANGE 

echo '<td> '.$data_q4[$z]['Date'].' </td>'; to 
echo '<td class=\"dates\"> '.$data_q4[$z]['Date'].' </td>';

-THEN

$("#myTable .dates").each(function(){
     $(this).html(ConvertDate($(this).html()));    
});
```

Comment: Hi @Nick how can I do this part
<some selector for your date time column>

Comment: gave your date time column a class name. The replace <some selector for your date time column> with that class name. I could be more specific if you updated your question with the source code for the table.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks @Nick